# Forward current ClaimsPrincipal to WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have a ASP.NET WebAPI which works perfect. When the Client calls my API I can read the User in the ApiController-Class and get the IPrincipal with all the values (it is a ClaimsPrincipal).

Now, my WebAPI calls another WebAPI. There is no authentication against this WebAPI. Then I read ghere the User from the ApiController-Class, it seems to be empty (and it is a WindowsPrincipal).

How can I forward the ClaimsPrincipal from the authenticated first WebAPI-Call to the second WebAPI, that I can there read the User-Data?

Comment: You want to forward the access or identity token to your web api and also authorize that web api to your oauth provider.

Comment: @Joost00719 I do not want to authorize. I only want to know the User-Id which has called the API.

Comment: I do not think that is actually possible. An alternative route could be to add the UserId as a header to all requests to the unauthenticated webapi and create a method in your Controller to read this header from the HttpContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass user user principals as a header value (converting to json or another string object notation) to another webapi. After that you can read the header value and can use it.